# Converting string to XMLDocument doesn't create text nodes

Tags: java, xml

here's my situation.

I have a string containing XML data:

```
<tag> 
    <anotherTag> data </anotherTag>
</tag>
```

I take that string and I run it through this code to convert it to a Document:

```
try {
  DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
  return builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(sXMLString)));
} 
catch (Exception e) {
  // Parser with specified options can't be built
  ceLogger.logError("Unable to build a new XML Document from string provided:\t" + e.getMessage());
  return null;
}
```

The resulting xml is almost perfect. Its missing the data however and looks like this:

```
<tag> 
    <anotherTag />
</tag>
```

How can I copy over the text when creating an XML Document and why is it removing the text in the first place?

Edit:
The actual problem ended up being something along the lines of this:
While parsing through the XML structure with my own function this line is there:

```
if (curChild.getNodeType()==Node.ELEMENT_NODE) 
   sResult.append(XMLToString((Element)children.item(i),attribute_mask));
```

But no such logic exists for TEXT nodes, so they are simply ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is correct. The only guess I can make is that you are outputting your code incorrectly. I've tested your code, and used the following method to output, and the XML was displayed correctly with the text node:

```
public static void outputXML(Document dom) throws TransformerException
{
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

    //initialize StreamResult with File object to save to file
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(dom);
    transformer.transform(source, result);

    String xmlString = result.getWriter().toString();
    System.out.println(xmlString);
}
```

The output was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<tag> <anotherTag> data </anotherTag>
</tag>
```

Comment: In my problem, the input is a string with valid XML and the output that I want is a Document object with the proper XML structure. Your code takes a Document and generates a string

Comment: Right, but when you returned builder.parse(...) you got a Document object. I simply passed this Document object into the outputXML method I wrote above to verify that the Document does in fact have the appropriate XML structure. I think that the method you wrote to output your XML document may be where the error is, not the Document data structure you're returning. Could you perhaps post how you are outputting your Document object to verify the resultant XML document?

Comment: You are correct sir. The function I'm using to translate this fails to capture text nodes, which is why its not showing up both when I try to view it and when I'm processing it through my code.